# Custom fields in a Ruby exception object not shown when inspecting

Tags: ruby, exception, introspection

If I create a class in Ruby, I can generally "see" its fields when using `inspect`:

```
>> class C; def initialize; @x=1; end; end
=> :initialize
>> C.new.inspect
=> "#<C:0x007fd5b9119c20 @x=1>"
```

This does not seem to hold true for exceptions:

```
>> class E < StandardError; def initialize; super("hello"); @y=2; end; end
=> :initialize
>> begin; raise E.new; rescue E => e; puts e.inspect; end 
#<E: hello>
=> nil
```

I would have expected this to show `#<E: hello @y=2>`! So naturally I went to [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Exception.html#method-i-inspect) and saw that the `Error` class specifically overrides `inspect` to "return this exception’s class name and message."

This leads me to believe that either (1) adding extra descriptive fields to an error object is a bad thing, or (2) the author of the Ruby `Error` class made a mistake, or (3) there is something inherently weird about error objects that an explicit override of `inspect` was needed!

I don't mean for this to be an opinion question. My programming question here is:

- If the answer is (1), and it is bad practice to add fields to an error object, **what should I do instead?**
- If the answer is (2), how *does* one get around this mess? Override `inspect` in one's custom error subclass?

Comment: `begin; raise E.new; rescue E => e; puts e.instance_variables; end` => `@y` So you still have access to instance variables.

Comment: Yes, and I am currently reading them fine with `attr_reader`. Seems odd, though, that someone explicitly overrode the normal behavior from `Object` which is very convenient for debugging. My conclusion was that if someone took the time to **suppress** the debugging help of _showing every instance variable_ then that person thought is was a dumb idea to add the instance variables in the first place, or expected subclasses to _add them back in_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the answer is (2), how does one get around this mess? Override
>   inspect in one's custom error subclass?

I do not know why would you want to have instance variables in error class, but if

> how does one get around this mess?

means

> where are the instance variables I have defined for the object?

the answer is as follows:

```
begin; raise E.new; rescue E => e; puts e.instance_variables; end
#=> @y
```

To have instance variables shown within `inspect` you will for sure have to override `inspect` method:

```
class E < StandardError
  def initialize
    super('hello')
    @y = 2
  end

  def inspect
    "<#{self.class}: #{message}, #{instance_variables.map { |v| "#{v}=#{instance_variable_get(v)}"}.join(', ')}>"
  end
end
begin; raise E.new; rescue E => e; puts e.inspect; end
#=> <E: hello, @y=2>
```

I do not see any mess here :)

Comment: Indeed that makes sense and that's what I was afraid of. I can read the instance variables just fine, and use `attr_reader`, etc. It's just a total shame really, that this behavior of showing all the instance variables exists in `Object`, then then was explicitly removed in `Error`, so that subclasses of `Error` need to put it back in. I don't understand why the designer of `Error` couldn't have left the default behavior in. Perhaps the person felt that `@message=` in the output was overkill?

Comment: @RayToal Can't tell why they have it overridden for sure, but my experience with using custom errors was always limited by just having access to errors's `message`.

Comment: I'm looking at putting a status code and offending object into the thrown error object. If this were Go or Swift or even Java we can return two values or use optionals. Seems like the exception is more Rubyish. I could be wrong.

Comment: @RayToal if you are interested in including additional information in an Error Object that is your prerogative. All things in Ruby are Objects and can be manipulated in any fashion you wish. How inspect represents them from a puts perspective has nothing to do with this. Are you planning on tearing this information out of the object by parsing the string that `inspect` returns? I certainly hope not.

Comment: Haha, not at all! :) Just casually "inspecting" by dumping. Rest assured I was getting the error object from a rescue clause and reading the additional status information via a method generated from `attr_reader`. I just wanted to feel better by _seeing_ the property when logging (that is, logging informally with `p` during a prototyping phase as opposed to `to_s`). After playing around a bit more, I've found that the status property wasn't really needed, but I still feel that because errors are simple Ruby objects why not dump the additional properties in `inspect`.